# cgroup oom-killer causing kernel panic

Tags: linux-kernel, out-of-memory, qemu, libvirt, cgroups

I am using cgroups with libvirt to limit the memory a group of qemu-kvm guests can use on a custom linux kernel 4.7.8. After doing a couple of tests with it I started seeing kernel panics after the oom-killer is called when that libvirt cgroup runs out of memory. That happens even when I set the cgroup memory way below the total and the system is idle besides running vms (loads of memory left for other tasks out of the cgroup). For the record, my system has 32GB and I was using 20GB for the guests cgroups.
Here is part of the the crash log (it is veeery long but I can link to the full log later):

```
    Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.727982] Call Trace:

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.727975]  0000000000000296 ffff8801f1638dc0 ffffffff811b50f6 ffff88083dff9800

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.728007]  [<ffffffff811608ce>] oom_kill_process+0xc2/0x487

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.728014]  [<ffffffff812e22c2>] ? selinux_capable+0x1f/0x21

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.727994]  [<ffffffff811b50f6>] ? mem_cgroup_select_victim_node+0x17d/0x1ac

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.728018]  [<ffffffff812d95ac>] ? security_capable_noaudit+0x2b/0x46

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.728028]  [<ffffffff811b235b>] ? mem_cgroup_iter+0x250/0x265

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.728025]  [<ffffffff811afd1c>] ? css_put+0x18/0x1a

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.728031]  [<ffffffff811607c1>] ? oom_badness+0x10f/0x15a

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.728036]  [<ffffffff811af46d>] ? get_mem_cgroup_from_mm+0x52/0x71

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.728039]  [<ffffffff811b4039>] mem_cgroup_out_of_memory+0x2c7/0x311

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.728054]  [<ffffffff81160ffd>] pagefault_out_of_memory+0x1f/0x76

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.728003]  [<ffffffff81171d2c>] ? try_to_free_mem_cgroup_pages+0x10d/0x16a

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.728061]  [<ffffffff810999bf>] mm_fault_error+0x66/0x103

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.727966] CPU: 1 PID: 15433 Comm: qemu-system-x86 Tainted: G           O    4.7.8 #25

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.728064]  [<ffffffff81099e4c>] __do_page_fault+0x3f0/0x4d8

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.728071]  [<ffffffff8109a043>] do_page_fault+0x26/0x2f

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.728068]  [<ffffffff81191a7d>] ? SyS_mremap+0x46c/0x4cf

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.728074]  [<ffffffff81a3dca8>] page_fault+0x28/0x30

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.728023]  [<ffffffff8111469e>] ? css_next_descendant_pre+0x32/0x53

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.728051]  [<ffffffff811b14d2>] ? mem_cgroup_count_precharge_pte_range+0xe8/0xe8

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.727999]  [<ffffffff8115fe5f>] dump_header+0x5e/0x286

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.728058]  [<ffffffff8118e399>] ? vma_adjust+0x4b5/0x58b

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.728047]  [<ffffffff811b43bb>] mem_cgroup_oom_synchronize+0x1ed/0x27b

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.728010]  [<ffffffff811b53f5>] ? task_in_mem_cgroup+0xc9/0xd6

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.727989]  [<ffffffff81336719>] dump_stack+0x65/0x8c

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.728044]  [<ffffffff810da147>] ? finish_wait+0x65/0x70

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.727979]  ffff8803259d7cf8 ffff8803259d7b38 ffffffff8115fe5f 024200ca00000003

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:57 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6380.727971]  ffff880802cbb700 ffff8803259d7a08 ffffffff81336719 ffff88081948fc00
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.727959] qemu-system-x86 invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x24000c0(GFP_KERNEL), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.727966] CPU: 1 PID: 15433 Comm: qemu-system-x86 Tainted: G           O    4.7.8 #25
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.727968] Hardware name: ADLINK TECHNOLOGY Inc. Express-SL/, BIOS 1.22.10.KA08 05/03/2017
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.727971]  ffff880802cbb700 ffff8803259d7a08 ffffffff81336719 ffff88081948fc00
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.727975]  0000000000000296 ffff8801f1638dc0 ffffffff811b50f6 ffff88083dff9800
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.727979]  ffff8803259d7cf8 ffff8803259d7b38 ffffffff8115fe5f 024200ca00000003
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.727982] Call Trace:
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.727989]  [<ffffffff81336719>] dump_stack+0x65/0x8c
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.727994]  [<ffffffff811b50f6>] ? mem_cgroup_select_victim_node+0x17d/0x1ac
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.727999]  [<ffffffff8115fe5f>] dump_header+0x5e/0x286
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728003]  [<ffffffff81171d2c>] ? try_to_free_mem_cgroup_pages+0x10d/0x16a
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728007]  [<ffffffff811608ce>] oom_kill_process+0xc2/0x487
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728010]  [<ffffffff811b53f5>] ? task_in_mem_cgroup+0xc9/0xd6
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728014]  [<ffffffff812e22c2>] ? selinux_capable+0x1f/0x21
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728018]  [<ffffffff812d95ac>] ? security_capable_noaudit+0x2b/0x46
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728023]  [<ffffffff8111469e>] ? css_next_descendant_pre+0x32/0x53
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728025]  [<ffffffff811afd1c>] ? css_put+0x18/0x1a
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728028]  [<ffffffff811b235b>] ? mem_cgroup_iter+0x250/0x265
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728031]  [<ffffffff811607c1>] ? oom_badness+0x10f/0x15a
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728036]  [<ffffffff811af46d>] ? get_mem_cgroup_from_mm+0x52/0x71
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728039]  [<ffffffff811b4039>] mem_cgroup_out_of_memory+0x2c7/0x311
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728044]  [<ffffffff810da147>] ? finish_wait+0x65/0x70
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728047]  [<ffffffff811b43bb>] mem_cgroup_oom_synchronize+0x1ed/0x27b
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728051]  [<ffffffff811b14d2>] ? mem_cgroup_count_precharge_pte_range+0xe8/0xe8
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728054]  [<ffffffff81160ffd>] pagefault_out_of_memory+0x1f/0x76
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728058]  [<ffffffff8118e399>] ? vma_adjust+0x4b5/0x58b
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728061]  [<ffffffff810999bf>] mm_fault_error+0x66/0x103
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728064]  [<ffffffff81099e4c>] __do_page_fault+0x3f0/0x4d8
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728068]  [<ffffffff81191a7d>] ? SyS_mremap+0x46c/0x4cf
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728071]  [<ffffffff8109a043>] do_page_fault+0x26/0x2f
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728074]  [<ffffffff81a3dca8>] page_fault+0x28/0x30
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728077] Task in /machine/ubc3.libvirt-qemu killed as a result of limit of /machine
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728082] memory: usage 31457280kB, limit 31457280kB, failcnt 0
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728084] memory+swap: usage 31457280kB, limit 31457280kB, failcnt 129072
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728086] kmem: usage 2200kB, limit 9007199254740988kB, failcnt 0
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728088] Memory cgroup stats for /machine: cache:0KB rss:0KB rss_huge:0KB mapped_file:0KB dirty:0KB writeback:0KB swap:0KB inactive_anon:0KB active_anon:0KB inactive_file:0KB active_file:0KB unevictable:0KB
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728102] Memory cgroup stats for /machine/ubc4.libvirt-qemu: cache:12KB rss:0KB rss_huge:0KB mapped_file:0KB dirty:0KB writeback:0KB swap:0KB inactive_anon:0KB active_anon:0KB inactive_file:8KB active_file:4KB unevictable:0KB
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728114] Memory cgroup stats for /machine/ubc1.libvirt-qemu: cache:32KB rss:6312484KB rss_huge:0KB mapped_file:20KB dirty:0KB writeback:0KB swap:0KB inactive_anon:16KB active_anon:6312488KB inactive_file:12KB active_file:0KB unevictable:0KB
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728126] Memory cgroup stats for /machine/ubc2.libvirt-qemu: cache:60KB rss:8408808KB rss_huge:0KB mapped_file:20KB dirty:0KB writeback:0KB swap:0KB inactive_anon:16KB active_anon:8408804KB inactive_file:20KB active_file:20KB unevictable:0KB
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728137] Memory cgroup stats for /machine/ubc3.libvirt-qemu: cache:60KB rss:8410240KB rss_huge:0KB mapped_file:20KB dirty:0KB writeback:0KB swap:0KB inactive_anon:16KB active_anon:8410244KB inactive_file:24KB active_file:16KB unevictable:0KB
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728149] Memory cgroup stats for /machine/ubc4.libvirt-qemu: cache:88KB rss:8323296KB rss_huge:0KB mapped_file:20KB dirty:0KB writeback:0KB swap:0KB inactive_anon:16KB active_anon:8323260KB inactive_file:32KB active_file:36KB unevictable:0KB
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728161] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728189] [ 5493]     0  5493  1626653  1580390    3170       9        0             0 qemu-system-x86
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728193] [15427]     0 15427  2151137  2104431    4195      11        0             0 qemu-system-x86
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728197] [17683]     0 17683  2151136  2104812    4195      11        0             0 qemu-system-x86
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728202] [18273]     0 18273  2152955  2083131    4156      12        0             0 qemu-system-x86
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728205] Memory cgroup out of memory: Kill process 17683 (qemu-system-x86) score 260 or sacrifice child
May 11 15:53:57  kernel: [ 6380.728217] Killed process 17683 (qemu-system-x86) total-vm:8604544kB, anon-rss:8409956kB, file-rss:9272kB, shmem-rss:20kB

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379203] CPU: 4 PID: 121 Comm: kworker/4:1 Tainted: G           O    4.7.8 #25

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379206] Hardware name: ADLINK TECHNOLOGY Inc. Express-SL/, BIOS 1.22.10.KA08 05/03/2017

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379222]  0000000000000296 000000000000039a 0000000000000000 ffffffff81f4b6bb

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379227]  0000000000000000 ffff8808038f7748 ffffffff810a938a 000000091d19fce0

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379232] Call Trace:

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379244]  [<ffffffff810a938a>] __warn+0xdc/0xf7

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379239]  [<ffffffff81336719>] dump_stack+0x65/0x8c

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379254]  [<ffffffff81034a38>] mmu_spte_clear_track_bits+0xe6/0x147

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379272]  [<ffffffff810353e7>] drop_spte+0x15/0xa4

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379267]  [<ffffffff810d3d7c>] ? update_group_capacity+0x25/0x1d0

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379282]  [<ffffffff81071dbe>] ? sched_clock+0x9/0xd

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379287]  [<ffffffff81035703>] kvm_mmu_prepare_zap_page+0x177/0x2ef

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379293]  [<ffffffff81069828>] ? __switch_to+0x458/0x4ea

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379298]  [<ffffffff810d04da>] ? sched_clock_cpu+0x21/0xb4

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379304]  [<ffffffff81a39517>] ? __schedule+0x56f/0x594

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379316]  [<ffffffff810363a7>] kvm_mmu_invalidate_zap_all_pages+0xcc/0x104

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379321]  [<ffffffff813498c2>] ? percpu_ref_put+0x2e/0x2e

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379327]  [<ffffffff8102800e>] kvm_arch_flush_shadow_all+0x9/0xb

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379346]  [<ffffffff81349bab>] ? percpu_ref_kill_and_confirm+0x60/0x65

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379337]  [<ffffffff811a600f>] __mmu_notifier_release+0x4d/0xe3

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379341]  [<ffffffff811ab39c>] ? kfree+0x167/0x178

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379357]  [<ffffffff811f4e9b>] ? exit_aio+0xc6/0xd5

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379367]  [<ffffffff810a6f30>] __mmput+0x19/0xbc

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379371]  [<ffffffff81a39517>] ? __schedule+0x56f/0x594

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379376]  [<ffffffff810a6fe3>] mmput_async_fn+0x10/0x12

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379387]  [<ffffffff81a396c6>] ? schedule+0x98/0xa6

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379407]  [<ffffffff810cf9d4>] ? default_wake_function+0xd/0xf

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379392]  [<ffffffff810c0ace>] worker_thread+0x36d/0x43c

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379397]  [<ffffffff81a39517>] ? __schedule+0x56f/0x594

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379413]  [<ffffffff810c0761>] ? process_one_work+0x353/0x353

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379417]  [<ffffffff81a396c6>] ? schedule+0x98/0xa6

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379422]  [<ffffffff810c0761>] ? process_one_work+0x353/0x353

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379426]  [<ffffffff810c49e8>] kthread+0xc8/0xd2

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379436]  [<ffffffff81a3bf3f>] ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x40

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379431]  [<ffffffff810c0761>] ? process_one_work+0x353/0x353

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379441]  [<ffffffff810c4920>] ? kthread_freezable_should_stop+0x61/0x61

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379457] Modules linked in: bridge stp llc ipip ip_gre vfio_iommu_type1 vfio_pci vfio vfio_virqfd qcserial qmi_wwan usbnet cdc_wdm clear_stats(O) fusion(O) gpio_pca953x i2c_i801 i2c_acpi_sbus(O) gpio_exar e1000e

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379481] Hardware name: ADLINK TECHNOLOGY Inc. Express-SL/, BIOS 1.22.10.KA08 05/03/2017

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379489]  ffffffff81f4b6bb ffff8808038f7708 ffffffff81336719 ffff880800294f00

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379486] Workqueue: events mmput_async_fn

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379494]  0000000000000296 dead000000000100 0000000000000000 ffffffff81f4b6bb

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379499]  0000000000000000 ffff8808038f7748 ffffffff810a938a 0000000900000100

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379504] Call Trace:

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379523]  [<ffffffff81034a38>] mmu_spte_clear_track_bits+0xe6/0x147

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379259]  [<ffffffff810d258f>] ? check_preempt_wakeup+0x115/0x1b4

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379263]  [<ffffffff81032058>] ? gfn_to_rmap+0x27/0x5a

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379527]  [<ffffffff810d258f>] ? check_preempt_wakeup+0x115/0x1b4

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379351]  [<ffffffff8118cfb3>] exit_mmap+0x22/0x102

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379331]  [<ffffffff8101a7f5>] kvm_mmu_notifier_release+0x2e/0x41

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379536]  [<ffffffff810d3d7c>] ? update_group_capacity+0x25/0x1d0

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379541]  [<ffffffff810353e7>] drop_spte+0x15/0xa4

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379550]  [<ffffffff81071dbe>] ? sched_clock+0x9/0xd

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379555]  [<ffffffff81035703>] kvm_mmu_prepare_zap_page+0x177/0x2ef

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379249]  [<ffffffff810a93bd>] warn_slowpath_null+0x18/0x1a

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379532]  [<ffffffff81032058>] ? gfn_to_rmap+0x27/0x5a

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379565]  [<ffffffff810d04da>] ? sched_clock_cpu+0x21/0xb4

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379382]  [<ffffffff810c0620>] process_one_work+0x212/0x353

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379570]  [<ffffffff81a39517>] ? __schedule+0x56f/0x594

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379580]  [<ffffffff810363a7>] kvm_mmu_invalidate_zap_all_pages+0xcc/0x104

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379585]  [<ffffffff813498c2>] ? percpu_ref_put+0x2e/0x2e

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379590]  [<ffffffff8102800e>] kvm_arch_flush_shadow_all+0x9/0xb

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379362]  [<ffffffff810d04da>] ? sched_clock_cpu+0x21/0xb4

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379595]  [<ffffffff8101a7f5>] kvm_mmu_notifier_release+0x2e/0x41

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379518]  [<ffffffff810a93bd>] warn_slowpath_null+0x18/0x1a

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379609]  [<ffffffff81349bab>] ? percpu_ref_kill_and_confirm+0x60/0x65

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379604]  [<ffffffff811ab39c>] ? kfree+0x167/0x178

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379619]  [<ffffffff811f4e9b>] ? exit_aio+0xc6/0xd5

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379614]  [<ffffffff8118cfb3>] exit_mmap+0x22/0x102

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379624]  [<ffffffff810d04da>] ? sched_clock_cpu+0x21/0xb4

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379637]  [<ffffffff810a6fe3>] mmput_async_fn+0x10/0x12

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379632]  [<ffffffff81a39517>] ? __schedule+0x56f/0x594

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379642]  [<ffffffff810c0620>] process_one_work+0x212/0x353

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379652]  [<ffffffff810c0ace>] worker_thread+0x36d/0x43c

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379647]  [<ffffffff81a396c6>] ? schedule+0x98/0xa6

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379277]  [<ffffffff81035513>] mmu_page_zap_pte+0x48/0xc1

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379600]  [<ffffffff811a600f>] __mmu_notifier_release+0x4d/0xe3

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379667]  [<ffffffff810cf9d4>] ? default_wake_function+0xd/0xf

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379672]  [<ffffffff810c0761>] ? process_one_work+0x353/0x353

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379661]  [<ffffffff810cf9ab>] ? try_to_wake_up+0x240/0x25c

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379681]  [<ffffffff810c0761>] ? process_one_work+0x353/0x353

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379574]  [<ffffffff814585e7>] ? extract_buf+0xf7/0x106
kernel: [ 6381.379696]  [<ffffffff81a3bf3f>] ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x40

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379686]  [<ffffffff810c49e8>] kthread+0xc8/0xd2

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379715] Modules linked in: bridge stp llc ipip ip_gre vfio_iommu_type1 vfio_pci vfio vfio_virqfd qcserial qmi_wwan usbnet cdc_wdm clear_stats(O) fusion(O) gpio_pca953x i2c_i801 i2c_acpi_sbus(O) gpio_exar e1000e

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379508]  [<ffffffff81336719>] dump_stack+0x65/0x8c

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379701]  [<ffffffff810c4920>] ? kthread_freezable_should_stop+0x61/0x61

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379545]  [<ffffffff81035513>] mmu_page_zap_pte+0x48/0xc1

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379736] CPU: 4 PID: 121 Comm: kworker/4:1 Tainted: G        W  O    4.7.8 #25

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379656]  [<ffffffff81a39517>] ? __schedule+0x56f/0x594

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379739] Hardware name: ADLINK TECHNOLOGY Inc. Express-SL/, BIOS 1.22.10.KA08 05/03/2017

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379743] Workqueue: events mmput_async_fn

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379760] Call Trace:

Message from syslogd@ at Fri May 11 15:53:58 2018 ...
 kernel: [ 6381.379750]  0000000000000296 dead000000000100 0000000000000000 ffffffff81f4b6bb
.
.
.

May 11 15:54:13  kernel: [ 6396.890938] Workqueue: events mmput_async_fn
May 11 15:54:13  kernel: [ 6396.890940]  ffffffff81f4b6bb ffff8808038f7708 ffffffff81336719 0000000000294f00
May 11 15:54:13  kernel: [ 6396.890945]  0000000000000296 ffffea0002d58220 0000000000000000 ffffffff81f4b6bb
May 11 15:54:13  kernel: [ 6396.890950]  0000000000000000 ffff8808038f7748 ffffffff810a938a 0000000902d58220
May 11 15:54:13  kernel: [ 6396.890954] Call Trace:
May 11 15:54:13  kernel: [ 6396.890958]  [<ffffffff81336719>] dump_stack+0x65/0x8c
May 11 15:54:13  kernel: [ 6396.890963]  [<ffffffff810a938a>] __warn+0xdc/0xf7
May 11 15:54:13  kernel: [ 6396.890968]  [<ffffffff810a93bd>] warn_slowpath_null+0x18/0x1a
May 11 15:54:13  kernel: [ 6396.890972]  [<ffffffff81034a38>] mmu_spte_clear_track_bits+0xe6/0x147
May 11 15:54:13  kernel: [ 6396.890977]  [<ffffffff81032058>] ? gfn_to_rmap+0x27/0x5a
May 11 15:54:13  kernel: [ 6396.890981]  [<ffffffff810353e7>] drop_spte+0x15/0xa4
May 11 15:54:13  kernel: [ 6396.890986]  [<ffffffff81035513>] mmu_page_zap_pte+0x48/0xc1
May 11 15:54:13  kernel: [ 6396.890990]  [<ffffffff8112b110>] ? kprobe_flush_task+0x8d/0xe8
May 11 15:54:13  kernel: [ 6396.890995]  [<ffffffff81035703>] kvm_mmu_prepare_zap_page+0x177/0x2ef
May 11 15:54:13  kernel: [ 6396.891000]  [<ffffffff810cee3a>] ? finish_task_switch+0x19f/0x1d5
May 11 15:54:13  kernel: [ 6396.891005]  [<ffffffff81a39517>] ? __schedule+0x56f/0x594
May 11 15:54:13  kernel: [ 6396.891009]  [<ffffffff81a39517>] ? __schedule+0x56f/0x594
May 11 15:54:13  kernel: [ 6396.891014]  [<ffffffff81a39562>] ? preempt_schedule_common+0x26/0x31
May 11 15:54:13  kernel: [ 6396.891020]  [<ffffffff810363a7>] kvm_mmu_invalidate_zap_all_pages+0xcc/0x104
May 11 15:54:13  kernel: [ 6396.891024]  [<ffffffff813498c2>] ? percpu_ref_put+0x2e/0x2e
May 11 15:54:13  kernel: [ 6396.891029]  [<ffffffff8102800e>] kvm_arch_flush_shadow_all+0x9/0x
```

I decided to try disabling the oom-killer on the cgroup and exhaust the cgroup memory to see what happens, and I was expecting the guests to hang until I manually killed one of them (as it is described in cgroup documentation). But surprisingly one of the guests(randomly it seems) gets killed everytime I repeat the test. I am quite confused because if the oom-killer is disabled what is killing the processes?

Here is the messages I get from the kernel on that case and also in the case when the oom-killer is enabled but the system does not crash:

```
kernel: [ 1143.934857]   cache: task_struct(10:ubc2.libvirt-qemu), 
object size: 3520, buffer size: 3520, default order: 3, min order: 0
kernel: [ 1143.934860]   node 0: slabs: 3, objs: 27, free: 0
kernel: [ 1143.944535] SLUB: Unable to allocate memory on node -1, 
gfp=0x24000c0(GFP_KERNEL)
kernel: [ 1143.944541]   cache: cred_jar(10:ubc2.libvirt-qemu), object 
size: 168, buffer size: 192, default order: 0, min order: 0
kernel: [ 1143.944545]   node 0: slabs: 2, objs: 42, free: 0
```

From my observations, it seems that there is something killing the processes before the oom-killer is called (when it is enabled), in which case the system will recover fine, but when the oom-killer does get called the system crashes and the machine needs a reboot.

So my questions are:

1. What can be causing the oom-killer to crash the machine?
2. What is killing the guests when the oom-killer is disabled?

It would be great if anyone has any clues on this matter!
Thanks!

Note: I am using kernel v4.7.8 built with buildroot and compiled with uClibc on a x86 platform. Also, no swap on this system.